# Cartesian product of subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X$ and $Y$ expressed as $X\times Y - (...)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $X$ and $Y$, respectively.
I've seen this written in a proof:
 $$A \times B = X\times Y - ((X-A)\times B \cup A\times(Y-B))$$

I think this is not correct, and I want to confirm it. I think one must have
 $$A \times B = X\times Y - ((X-A)\times B \cup A\times(Y-B)\cup ((X-A)\times(Y-B)))$$

In fact, in the first case one would have that $(x,y)\in A\times B$ for $x\in (X-A)$ and $y \in (Y-B)$, which is incorrect.

Comment: After seeing the proof again, I noticed that it was written  $$A \times B = X\times Y - ((X-A)\times Y \cup X\times(Y-B))$$ after all. This excludes the case I was worried about. I leave the question here anyway because I would still like someone to confirm it.

Comment: Is $A - B$ the set-theoretic difference of $A$ and $B$ (all elements of $A$ that are not in $B$)?

Comment: Yes, it is the set-theoretic difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula from your comment is correct.

Observe that for sets $C, D, E, F$ we have
$$ C-(D\cup E)=(C-D)\cap (C-E),$$
$$(C-D)\times E=C\times E - D\times E,$$
and $$(C\times D)\cap (E\times F)=(C\cap E)\times (D\cap F).$$

Using these three facts you obtain 
$$X\times Y-((X-A)\times Y\cup X\times (Y-B))=(X\times Y-((X-A)\times Y))\cap (X\times Y-(X\times (Y-B)))=
((X-(X-A))\times Y)\cap (X\times (Y-(Y-B)))=(A\times Y)\cap(X\times B)=A\times B.$$

Comment: I would like to practice calculations with set operations (differences, cartesian products, unions and intersections). Could you tell me a good place to look for some exercises like those with solutions? Everything I find focuses on the theory (of sets), not on the calculations.

Comment: Pfff, I'm afraid that not:( I myself learned that in school, but not from a book.